# Do I need "it" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Vegetables and beer wasn't a typical mix. But one Tom enjoyed (it)
>   because half of it came from his wife's hands.

Why or why not?

Comment: Adding "it" changes the meaning/use of the word "one". Without "it", "one" refers to the mix (as stangdon says). With "it", "one" counts the number of Toms (making "one" synonymous with "a particular").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need *it* because *it* functions as a reference or a placeholder for something else.  For example, consider

> I like **this car**.
>   I like **it**.
>   **This car** is red.
>   **It** is red.

*it* is taking the place of *this car*.  You wouldn't say

> I like it this car

or

> This car it is red

In your example sentence, you already have a reference to "the mix of vegetables and beer":  **one**.  So because you already have a reference to the mix, you don't need *it*.  The redundancy of *it* might be clearer if you made the reference more explicit: "But *(it was)* one *(that)* Tom enjoyed..."  Obviously it doesn't make sense to say "It was one that Tom enjoyed it."